Is there a way to change a pacemaker resource's op stop timeout using crm from the command line?
I have defined a resource primitive in my corosync/pacemaker cluster. I want to be able to write a script that will change the resource's "op stop timeout" value from the command line without using the interactive "CRM configure edit." Is there a way to do this?
David
